# How to stop thread freezing when opening programs in python

Tags: python, multithreading, freeze

I have a simple program, part of which is to open other programs, for example a web browser.

It does this fine with `os.system(sudo "program")` but once the program is open I can't do anything with the original python program until the new one closes. Is there any way I could stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

subprocess. Subprocess module return control to python and get result via a pipe.

```
import subprocess as sp
proc = sp.Popen(["program", "arg1", "arg2"], shell=False, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
ret, err = proc.communicate()
```

„program” start at proc= .... but the result (mesages, errors) come into pipe when you call proc.communicate(); you can skip stderr=sp.PIPE if it is not the case.